# Is there a reason to use std::distance() over iterator::operator-()?

Tags: c++, std

I am unsure why there is both `std::distance(iterator const&, iterator const&)` and a `iterator::operator-(iterator const&)` (as well as adaptors `operator-(iterator const&, iterator const&)`), where `iterator` is a placeholder for any iterator.  Should one be used over the other, and if so, what circumstances?

Comment: Is `c++-standard-library` a better tag than `stl`?  `stl` looks to have a larger number associated with it.

Comment: The STL was/is a library that was created before C++ was standardized.  When C++98 was standardized, it came with it its own standard library, which is the C++ standard library, and it modeled a lot of the STL.  The names get used interchangeably incorrectly in a lot of places so the confusion is understandable.  In this case, the current tag would be the correct one.  This is like how ranges-v3 "is now" `<ranges>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`operator -` is not a member of most iterator types, so it is an error to use it generically unless your algorithm only supports random access.

`std::distance` on the other hand knows about iterator categories and will use `operator -` if it is available and if not, it will use `N` calls to `operator --` to do the subtraction.

Comment: Ok, so why not just have an `operator-(iterator const&)` defined for all iterators rather than have a separate `distance(iterator const&, iterator const&)`  function?

Comment: @Adrian - An expensive operation should not be hidden behind an one token function name. `std::distance` opts you in to paying the price if you are willing to accept it.

Comment: @Adrian Because they did not want to hide `O(N)` implementations.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that.  So if I do want to use `operator-`, and I then want to generalize it for other iterator types, this will shout out that doing so will add runtime complexity.

Answer (score 6):

Well, subtracting two iterators is not supported by all iterators. For some, it doesn't even make sense, putting aside the violated performance constraints (it should be O(1), not O(n)). And even if it is, why do you think the iterator is a class-type?

`std::distance()` thus falls back to iterating until the distance is covered as a fallback, which is a basic iterator-operation.

That degradation is not always acceptable though, and if it happens the distance better be positive, on pain of UB.

Still, especially when writing generic code (or code which might be generalized later), staying generic is good:
Write to the interface (the *minimal* one you need), not the implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by a "class-type"?

Comment: A class-type is defined using `class` or `struct`. But a `T*` is a perfectly fine iterator too.

Comment: Oh, I though that you were talking about something else.  Not sure why you have that sentence in there.  Doesn't add anything and is confusing because I'm expecting it to.

Comment: `T*` is a bad example, as pointers are (the archetypical) random access iterators

Comment: @Caleth, so you are saying that the sentence with "class-type" is useful for other reasons?

Comment: @Adrian I think they refer to your "`iterator::operator-(iterator const&)`" in the question. When the iterator isnt a class type then `operator-` cannot be a member function. And somehow you have that as premise to your question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, still don't see that adding anything but confusion to this answer.

Comment: If you only care about the call site, `T*` is not a compelling counter argument for "use `-`". Member vs non-member is a distraction

Comment: @Adrian frankly, the confusion is in the question. I don't quite understand what you mean with `iterator::operator-(iterator const&)`. Are you refering to [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)? This really was a source of confusion and luckily got deprecated

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that.  I was meaning iterator generically.  Didn't really know how to write that.  Edited the question.